# Can I Use External JS libraries in DialogFlow

Tags: reactjs, npm, dialogflow-es, swiper.js

I want to know if I can use external js libraries in dialogflow like react to create a component, and use another library like swiper js to create a sort of carousel that I would map payload data returned from my own server with axios to display a carousel inline as a response to the user

Comment: yes you can, if you tried and getting error update your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to use external js with the help of webhook functionality. Configure your intent and in fulfillment page, configure your webhook. Please refer to this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/fulfillment-overview) for more info.

It's also possible with integrating other tools, more are available [here](https://www.kommunicate.io/blog/integrate-dialogflow-bot-react-js/)